# Convert javascript date to json date format

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working with an API which expects json date format.

I need to convert my javascript date

> Sat Jan 17 1970 07:28:19 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)

To json date format

> /Date(1405699200)/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is anything of the following ok?

```js
console.log(new Date('Sat Jan 17 1970 07:28:19 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)').toJSON());
console.log(new Date('Sat Jan 17 1970 07:28:19 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)').valueOf());
```

Comment: new Date('Sat Jan 17 1970 07:28:19 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)').valueOf() works fine! Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

```
/Date(1405699200)/
```

Here `1405699200` is your date in epoch format.

You can do this :

```
var myDate = new Date("July 1, 1978 02:30:00"); // Your timezone!
var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000.0;
document.write(myEpoch);
```

To convert human readable date format to Epoch format : https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/#javascript